# Mongoose.js unable to get an array from my document

Tags: json, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

In my mongoose models I have a User Schema like this:

```
var userSchema = mongoose.Schema({
_id : String,
username: String,
name : String,
timestamp : { type : Date, default: Date.now },
admin : Boolean,
pages : [String]
});
var User = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);
```

and I am trying to get the pages array from that document like this:

```
function isUserPage(userId, pageId, callback) {
models.User.find({_id: userId}, function(err, user) {
    console.log('user pages: ' + JSON.stringify(user[0].pages));
...
});
```

The problem is that my console.log is outputting [ [object object] ]. I can see the array with its data in smog (a web based mongodb admin viewer), but I can't seem to access it with javascript.

Thank-you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

console will always print the array with objects as [object object]. 
`pages` is actually an array of object, So you can specify an index to the pages array like this

```
console.log(user[0].pages[0]);
```

or if the `pages` array contain more than one element you want a regular for loop

```
for (var i = 0; i<user[0].pages.length; i++) {
  // use i as an array index
  console.log(user[0].pages[i]);
}
```